# Convert string "5m 12s 635ms" to "05:12:635"

Tags: java

I need to convert strings that look like these:

"5m 12s 635ms"
"5m 12s"
"12s 635ms"
etc.

NOTE: The string may or may not contain any of the individual time elements.

To a format of:
hh:mm:ss.SSS

Is there a simple way of doing this?  I looked at simpledateformat and it won't take the input string to convert.

-Greg

Comment: You could use regular expressions to parse the input string. You can try them out at regex101.com

Comment: Split at the space, loop over the parts, check if they end with one of your units (s, ms, m, ...) and construct a date or String from the result.

Comment: You could try to use two `SimpleDateFormat`s, one for parsing and one for formatting the string.

Comment: Tip: Better to use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) standard strings (ex: `PT5M12.635S`) for a span-of-time, with Java class `java.time.Duration`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To a format of: hh:mm:ss.SSS

This works as follows:

- convert `xxs` and `yyyms` to `xx.yyys`
- then simply parse the durations and add to a `LocalTime` instance

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] times = { "5m 12s 635ms", "5m 12s", "12s 635ms",
            "1h  17m 12s 998ms", "2h 222ms" };

    for (String tm : times) {
        System.out.printf("%18s --> %10s%n",tm, formatTime(tm));
    }
}

public static String formatTime(String time) {
    // modify seconds for Duration parse    
    String modtm =  time.replaceAll("(\\d+)s\\s+(\\d+)ms", "$1.$2s")
                        .replaceAll("(\\d+)ms", "0.$1s");

    // now build up the local time value
    LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of(0, 0);
    for (String v : modtm.split("\\s+")) {
        lt = lt.plus(Duration.parse("PT" + v));
    }
    return lt.format(
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
}
```

Prints

```
      5m 12s 635ms --> 00:05:12.635
            5m 12s --> 00:05:12.000
         12s 635ms --> 00:00:12.635
 1h  17m 12s 998ms --> 01:17:12.998
          2h 222ms --> 02:00:00.222
```

It would have been much simpler if your seconds were already in ss.sss format (e.g 
12.635s).  But the `replaceAll` took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a supporting library/method in jdk/joda. If you are okay to use a custom method, here is one that you can use.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "5m 12s 635ms";
        String input2 = "5m 12s";
        String input3 = "12s 635ms";
        String input4 = "6h 5m 12s 635ms";

        System.out.println(formatter(input));
        // 00:05:12.635
        System.out.println(formatter(input2));
        // 00:05:12.000
        System.out.println(formatter(input3));
        // 00:00:12.635        
        System.out.println(formatter(input4));
        // 06:05:12.635
    }
    String formatter(String input) {
        String[] inputArray = input.split(" ");
        String format = "";
        long h = 0, m = 0, s = 0, ms = 0;
        for (String i : inputArray) {
            if (i.endsWith("ms")) {
                ms = Long.valueOf(i.replace("ms", ""));

            } else if (i.endsWith("h")) {
                h = Long.valueOf(i.replace("h", ""));
            } else if (i.endsWith("m")) {
                m = Long.valueOf(i.replace("m", ""));
            } else if (i.endsWith("s")) {
                s = Long.valueOf(i.replace("s", ""));
            }
        }
        format = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", h, m, s, ms);
        return format;
    }
```